# How to get person name and other attributes from Wikidata Sparql (resolving entities)?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I have this Node.js sparql fetcher from Wikidata:

```
next()

async function next(offset = 0) {
  const sparql = `
  SELECT ?person ?pic ?givenName ?familyName ?placeOfBirth
  WHERE {
    ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
    ?person wdt:P18 ?pic .
    ?person wdt:P735 ?givenName .
    ?person wdt:P734 ?familyName .
    ?person wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  }
  OFFSET ${offset}
  LIMIT 50`
  const query = new URLSearchParams({ query: sparql }).toString();
  const url = ` https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql?${query}`
  console.log(url)
  const res = await fetch(url, { headers: { Accept: 'application/sparql-results+json' } })
  const json = await res.json()
  const array = json.results.bindings
  if (!array.length) {
    return
  }
  console.log(array)
}
```

However, it is returning an array of values like this:

```
{
  person: { type: 'uri', value: 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q15198783' },
  placeOfBirth: { type: 'uri', value: 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q61' },
  familyName: { type: 'uri', value: 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2658150' },
  pic: {
    type: 'uri',
    value: 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Charles%20Baker%202016.jpg'
  },
  givenName: { type: 'uri', value: 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2958359' }
}
```

The `pic` is at least resolved, but everything else is not. How can I just get both the entity ID for each, *as well as* the resolved literal value for it, for all these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select additional variables on the pattern `${variableName}Label`:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?pic ?givenName ?givenNameLabel ?familyName ?familyNameLabel ?placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirthLabel
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  ?person wdt:P18 ?pic .
  ?person wdt:P735 ?givenName .
  ?person wdt:P734 ?familyName .
  ?person wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 50
```

See the [User Manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service) for more details